# Codeigniter Error Unable to locate the specified class: Loader.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

i am trying to make a core class in my codeigniter but its giving error that Unable to locate the specified class: Loader.php.
My Core class is MY_base.php and code is.

```
     class MY_base extends CI_Controller{

 public function load_header(){


     $this->load->model('mod_practice');
     $headData=$this->model->get_header();


$this->load->view('header',$headData); 

     }



 }
```

My model Mod_practice.php code is

```
  class Mod_practice extends CI_Model{


 public function get_header(){

     $query = $this->db->get('header');
     $result = $query->result_array();
     return $result;

     }

 }
```

My home.php ( main controller) code is 
class Home extends MY_loader{

```
function index(){

    parent::MY_base();

    }

}
```

but when i try to run Home controller its giving me the following error
Unable to locate the specified class: Loader.php.
Where can be the error ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ditch the whole "MY_" business and just name your classes what they are... So MY_base would become Base_Controller . Try that out!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong. You need to construct CI_controller first.

```
class MY_base extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct()
  {
          parent::__construct();
          // Your own constructor code
  }

 public function load_header(){
     $this->load->model('mod_practice');
     $headData=$this->model->get_header();

     $this->load->view('header',$headData); 

     }
}
```

And now you can do this:

```
class Home extends MY_base{
      public function __construct()
      {
              parent::__construct();
              // Here you have access to load_header() function
      }

}
```

Ou - and also your create MY_base and then refer to MY_loader.

Answer (score -1):

may bee you can use HMVC Codeigniter https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc